# How to reference/define an array in one cell?

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I'm using countifs with an array to search for and count specific names from a column.

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:C10,{"Tom"; "Sam"; "Bill"})))`

However, the array is likely to change, so rather than change the formula, I want to use a separate cell to "store" the array for the formula to reference.

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:C10,D1)))`
Where D1 = {"Tom"; "Sam"; "Bill"}

Is there a way to reference an array from a different cell in a formula? Or is there a work around to accomplish the same thing? The "array reference cell" needs to be a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let D1 be:

```
(?i)Tom|Sam|Bill
```

and formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A1:C10; D1)*1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula** to count the number of times each name appears in the list "Array" *To Count* in column `E`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A1:C; 
 REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("|";;UNIQUE($E$2:$E));".\z";"")))
```

[image]